# "Session" tracking seems broken

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I have Facebook ads that bring users to a website. Each ad has a different tracking ID:
www.scaredycut.com/index.php?azn=TRACKING_ID

Once on the site, the tracking ID is inserted into the link to Amazon (so as to indicate a referral sale if something is bought). If a user comes to the site directly (not through an ad), they receive the tracking ID scaredycut-direct.

I set up two lines of defense: first, a cookie is created that contains TRACKING_ID. In case cookies are disabled, the url tag is still there (azn=TRACKING_ID), up for grabs.

In index.php, an initial php file that redirects to the home page:

```
# capture TRACKING_ID from URL
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$parsed_url = parse_url($actual_link);
$azn = substr($parsed_url[query], 4);

# save tag into a cookie set to expire in 30 days
setcookie ("ScaredyCut_AmazonReferral1", $azn,time()+60*60*24*30);
```

In the Wordpress' functions.php:

```
# create TRACKING_ID variable from url tag
$urltrackingID = $_GET["azn"];
# create TRACKING_ID variable from cookie
$cookietrackingID = $_COOKIE["ScaredyCut_AmazonReferral1"];

# logic: which variable to use?
if ($cookietrackingID == NULL) { // if there's no cookie,
        if ($urltrackingID == NULL) { // if they came directly,
            $trackingID = "scaredycut-direct"; // use tracking ID "scaredycut-direct"
        } else {    // otherwise, cookies are disabled, so use url tracking ID
            $trackingID = $urltrackingID;   
        }
    } else {    // otherwise, cookie are enabled, so use cookie tracking ID
        $trackingID = $cookietrackingID;
    }
```

In header.php:

```
# declare global tracking ID var
<?php 
    global $trackingID; 
?>
```

And then, I just insert $trackingID into the link's href. (I give precedence to cookies. If they have cookies on, I'd rather make a cookie in case they leave and come back later.)

My method is working, for the most part (surprising for the novice I am). Sessions are being tracked correctly, but I have a very strong suspicion that some sessions are being mistakenly tracked as "scaredycut-direct" instead of their ad-specific tracking ID.

The site is, for the most part, a single page. There isn't really a way for a user to lose a url tag by navigating to another page.

Is there a way that sessions are being marked incorrectly as "scaredycut-direct", and bypassing the cookie AND the url tag methods? Is there another way to do this?

Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: You could just replace basically your entire functions.php snippet with `$trackingID = $_COOKIE[...] or $_GET['azn'] or 'scaredycut-direct'` and achieve the same effect. But that has nothing to do with getting around it.

Answer (score 0):

A third option to **add** is `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, but it's set by the browser and isn't reliable. It also means that if they come from google, it'll be set to google.

Other than that, it looks okay.